# How can I monitor the change of a variable in my factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a very simple preloading screen script that i need to get from several controllers. However I can't get it to update automatically the variable and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**Factory:**

```
myApp.factory("preloader", function(){

    var preload = {};

    preload.loaded = true; 

    preload.turnOn = function () {
      preload.loaded = true;
      console.log('on');
    }

    preload.turnOff = function () {
      preload.loaded = false;
      console.log('off');
    }

    preload.getState = function() {
      return preload.loaded;
    }


    return preload;

});
```

**Controller**

```
mazda.controller('preloadingHome', ['$scope', "preloader", function($scope, preload) {  
  $scope.users       = false;
    $scope.showPreload = preload.getState();
  console.log(preload.loaded);

   $scope.turnOn = function(){
       preload.turnOn();
   }

  $scope.turnOff = function(){
       preload.turnOff();
  }  
  // 
  // $scope.state = preload.state;
  // preload.turnOff();

}]);
```

**View**

```
<body data-ng-controller="preloadingHome">
    <div>aaa: {{ showPreload }}</div>
    <div>b: {{users}} </div>

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="users" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="turnOff()" ng-model="pene" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="turnOn()" ng-model="pene2" />
    <!-- script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script -->
    <script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>  
</body>
```

My problem is: The {{ showPreload }} variable load on the view always stays true no matter how I change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is important to point out that the reason this does not work is because your getState() method returns by value, not by reference.

When your controller instantiates, it sets the `showPreloaded` variable to the value of the `preloaded.loaded` object member, which is `true`. Every time you change the state after that, you are updating the object member in your factory properly, but the `$scope.showPreloaded` value is equal to true, as it is not referencing the value in the factory.

Here is how to change your code:

In the view

```
<div>aaa: {{ showPreload.loaded }}</div>
```

In the factory:

```
preload.getState = function() {
  return preload;
}
```

The factory will now be returning the reference to the object preload. Javascript always returns references when returning an object, and returns the value when returning a primitive

Answer (score 1):

Your factory's method is not a two-way binding, instead, expose a variable from your factory/service, and bind to that, for example

```
factory.state = { isTurnedOn : true };
```

you can either directly bind to that factory variable, or have your controller own variable linked to the factory variable

Answer (score 1):

Return the whole object rather than returning a primitive. There is no inheritance of primitives

In factory

```
preload.getState = function() {
  return preload;
}
```

In controller

```
$scope.preloadState = preload.getState();
```

In view

```
<div>aaa: {{ preloadState.preload ?'Yes':'No'}}</div>
```

Now angular view watchers will detect property changes of the object and update view

Answer (score 0):

You should try to write this: `scope.preload = preloader;`

And then you can manipulate your object scope.preload.